# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError Jackrabbit FirstHop example

Tags: java, maven, jackrabbit

I am new to Maven and Jackrabbit and I am starting with FirstHops example given on Apache site but I am getting below error when trying to run. Not sure what to check.

```
S:\mvnapp\FirstHop2>java -cp target\FirstHop2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.shobhan.jr.Fi
rstHopSB
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jcr/Credentials

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jcr.Credentials
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: org.shobhan.jr.FirstHopSB.  Program will exit.
```

Below is Pom.xml file, i have added the dependencies as provided on apache site.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.shobhan.jr</groupId>
  <artifactId>FirstHop2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>FirstHop2</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

    <dependencies> 
    <!-- The JCR API --> 
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>javax.jcr</groupId> 
            <artifactId>jcr</artifactId> 
            <version>2.0</version> 
        </dependency> 
        <!-- Jackrabbit content repository --> 
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.apache.jackrabbit</groupId> 
            <artifactId>jackrabbit-core</artifactId> 
            <version>2.9.0</version> 
        </dependency> 
        <!-- Use Log4J for logging --> 
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> 
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId> 
            <version>1.7.5</version> 
        </dependency> 
    </dependencies> 
</project>
```

My env. has below values.

CLASSPATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin;S:\JR\jackrabbit-standalone-2.8.0.jar
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17

M2_HOME=S:\maven\apache-maven-3.2.5
PATH=%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;S:\maven\apache-maven-3.2.5\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin

Comment: There should be no space at all: `java -cp target\FirstHop2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar org.shobhan.jr.FirstHopSB`?

Comment: Provide your Maven POM xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you don't include your dependencies in your target jar:
add this to your pom.xml:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>com.mypackage.main.Main</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

and then run goal :

```
clean package assembly:single
```

Comment: I have added these dependencies in pom.xml file only.